# Variable is uninitialized

Tags: if-statement, sas, initialization, global, public

New to SAS, trying to call variable but it looks like I'm doing it the wrong way, always get uninitialized message. Here's my code:

```
%let monthNum=1;
%let PreviousYear=annee-1;
%let annee=2023;



data new;
/* I know this is working that way but want to call variable outside that code, define previously */
/*monthNum=1;
annee=2023;
PreviousYear=annee-1;*/
if monthNum=1 then PreviousYear=PreviousYear;
else PreviousYear=annee;

run;
```

Expect to declare public variable and call them.

Comment: What do you mean by "public variable"?  Those words make no sense.  Variables exist in datasets.  Macro variables (also called symbols) are not variables.

Comment: For date incrementation you should use full SAS dates and INTNX function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of data/proc step processing as 2 parts: compilation phase and execution phase. When you submit code to run, the compilation phase begins.

Here are some actions that are taken during the compilation phase:

- Syntax is checked
- The program data vector (PDV) is built
- Macro code is executed and macro variables are resolved
- Code is compiled

After the compilation phase, the execution of the takes place.

- The compiled data/procedure code is executed
- Input data is processed
- Output data is created

In your example, you create a macro variable `anee`. The macro code that assigns the value is executed during the compilation phase before the data step is executed. To use the macro variable in your data step, you need to create a data step variable `anee` that is assigned the value of the macro variable `anee`.

```
%let anee = 2023;

data new;
anee = &anee;
run;
```

Comment: Your third bullet point should be the first.  SAS does not begin evaluating the SAS code syntax until the macro processor has finished generating it.

Answer (score 0):

You get uninitialized messages because your data step contains this statement:

```
if monthNum=1 then PreviousYear=PreviousYear;
```

but your data step does not contain any variable named MONTHNUM.

If you want use the macro variable MONTHNUM to generate some SAS code then you need to use &MONTHNUM to reference the value of the macro variable.

```
if &monthNum=1 then PreviousYear=PreviousYear;
```

The macro processor will convert that into this SAS statement:

```
if 1=1 then PreviousYear=PreviousYear;
```

And now you will not get any uninitialized messages about the variable MONTHNUM because now your code never tries to reference that non-existent variable.

If the goal was just to calculate the value of the macro variable PREVIOUSYEAR then you can do that with just macro code, so no need to write a data step or any other SAS code at all.

```
%let monthNum=1;
%let annee=2023;
%if &monthnum=1 %then %do;
   %let PreviousYear=%eval(&annee-1);
%end;
%else %do;
   %let PreviousYear=&annee;
%end;
```

Comment: Yes Tom, it's exactly what I'm trying to do. But your code give met that message:ERROR: The %IF statement is not valid in open code. .Please not I'm usung SAS EG 7.1

Comment: The version of the tool you are using to submit the code to SAS does not matter.   Your EG project must be connected to a SAS server that is running a VERY old version of SAS.  You can definitely use %IF in open code in SAS 9.4M5 which was released in 2017.  In older version you can wrap the %IF in a macro definition and then execute the macro.

Comment: Here is a work around that works since you want to subtract either 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE). `%let PreviousYear=%eval(&annee-(&monthnum=1));`

Comment: Yes!! got it, tha,s all I need !